# Getting the URI from an Android NFC Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, uri, nfc, ndef

I'm writing an app that can listen for NFC tags with a URI scheme.

I've got an intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
  <data android:scheme="[theschemeofmyuri]" />
</intent-filter>
```

and the activity is being launched correctly for my NFC tags. Now I've written an unholy chunk of code to try and extract the URI, though I've removed the error handling to make it easier to read on SO:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();

NdefMessage[] msgs;

Parcelable[] rawMsgs = intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

msgs = new NdefMessage[rawMsgs.length];
for (int i = 0; i < rawMsgs.length; i++) {
    msgs[i] = (NdefMessage) rawMsgs[i];
}

NdefRecord[] recs = msgs[0].getRecords();

Log.i(TAG, new String(recs[0].getPayload(), "UTF-8"));
```

This seems to be printing it out with a null byte at the start.

The thing is, I know the URI has already been parsed by the system for the intent filter. Do I need to parse it again now? What about this null byte. Can I just ignore it?

The real question is, is there a simpler way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using the `NDEF_DISCOVERED` intent filter to trigger the app upon tags with URI records, the easiest method to retrieve the URI that triggered the app is to query the intent for its data URI:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri uri = intent.getData();                 // retrieve a Uri object instance or
String uriString = intent.getDataString();  // retrieve the string representation of the URI
```

Alternatively you can process the full NDEF message received from the tag and decode the URI from it. Note that this can get complex in some cases (e.g. if a Smart Poster record is used). Assuming that you already extracted the URI record from the NDEF message (either the first record or a URI record nested inside the first record if the first record is a Smart Poster record), you would then need to decode the record's payload according to the NFC Forum's URI Record Type Definition specification:

```
NdefRecord uriRecord = ...;
byte[] payload = uriRecord.getPayload();

int prefixCode = payload[0] & 0x0FF;
if (prefixCode >= URI_PREFIX.length) prefixCode = 0;

String reducedUri = new String(payload, 1, payload.length - 1, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

String uri = URI_PREFIX[prefixCode] + reducedUri;
```

With `URI_PREFIX` defined as:

```
final String[] URI_PREFIX = new String[] {
    /* 0x00 */ "",
    /* 0x01 */ "http://www.",
    /* 0x02 */ "https://www.",
    /* 0x03 */ "http://",
    /* 0x04 */ "https://",
    /* 0x05 */ "tel:",
    /* 0x06 */ "mailto:",
    /* 0x07 */ "ftp://anonymous:anonymous@",
    /* 0x08 */ "ftp://ftp.",
    /* 0x09 */ "ftps://",
    /* 0x0A */ "sftp://",
    /* 0x0B */ "smb://",
    /* 0x0C */ "nfs://",
    /* 0x0D */ "ftp://",
    /* 0x0E */ "dav://",
    /* 0x0F */ "news:",
    /* 0x10 */ "telnet://",
    /* 0x11 */ "imap:",
    /* 0x12 */ "rtsp://",
    /* 0x13 */ "urn:",
    /* 0x14 */ "pop:",
    /* 0x15 */ "sip:",
    /* 0x16 */ "sips:",
    /* 0x17 */ "tftp:",
    /* 0x18 */ "btspp://",
    /* 0x19 */ "btl2cap://",
    /* 0x1A */ "btgoep://",
    /* 0x1B */ "tcpobex://",
    /* 0x1C */ "irdaobex://",
    /* 0x1D */ "file://",
    /* 0x1E */ "urn:epc:id:",
    /* 0x1F */ "urn:epc:tag:",
    /* 0x20 */ "urn:epc:pat:",
    /* 0x21 */ "urn:epc:raw:",
    /* 0x22 */ "urn:epc:",
    /* 0x23 */ "urn:nfc:"
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Found it on a re-read of the documentation.

> `record.toUri()` - Map this record to a URI, or return null if it cannot be mapped

Unfortunately this is from API level 16, and I was hoping to support 15+. I'd still like an answer that works backwards-compatibly if possible.